# Create Trigger to get hourly difference between timestamps

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where I would like to calculate the difference in time (in hours) between two columns after inserting a row.  I would like to set up a trigger to do this whenever an insert or update is performed on the table.

My columns are delay_start, delay_stop, and delay_duration.  I would like to do the following:

delay_duration = delay_stop - delay_start

The result should be of numeric (4,2) value and go into the delay_duration category.  Below is what I have so far, but it will not populate the column for some reason.

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO public.deckdelays(delay_duration)
VALUES(DATEDIFF(hh, delay_stop, delay_start));
RETURN NEW;
END;
```

I am quite new to all of this so if anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are you sure you are using PostgreSQL? There is no `datediff()` function in Postgres

Comment: Yes I'm using postgres.  Perhaps that is why my function isn't working.  I have also tried this but to no avail:

`NEW.delay_duration = extract(epoch from (NEW.delay_stop - NEW.delay_start))/3600 as diff_hours;`

Comment: Be careful about using triggers. They will get very annoying. Maybe consider changing the way you insert so that you include duration, or you insert then update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Postgres 12 or later you can define delay_duration as a generated column. This allows you to eliminate triggers.

```
create table deckdelays(id           integer generated always as identity
                       , delay_start timestamp   
                       , delay_stop  timestamp
                       , delay_duration numeric(4,2)
                              generated always as 
                              ( extract(epoch from (delay_stop - delay_start))/3600 )
                              stored
                        --, other attributes
                       );
```

See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8cd41a8fa4d125718cda57fe7beb99c3).

---

But if you insist on a trigger:

```
create or replace 
function delayduration_func()
 returns trigger 
language plpgsql 
as $$
begin
    new.delay_duration = (extract(epoch from (deckdelays.delay_stop - deckdelays.delay_start))/3600)::numeric;
return new;
end;
$$;

create trigger delaydurationset1
before insert 
    or update of delay_stop, delay_start 
    on deckdelays
execute procedure delayduration_func();
```

Changes:

- Before trigger instead of after. A before trigger can modify the
  values in a column without additional DML statements, an after
  trigger cannot. Issuing a DML statement on a table within a trigger
  on that same table can lead to all types of problems. It is bast
  avoided if possible.
- Trigger name and function name not the same. Might just be me but I
  do not like different things having the same name. Although it works
  often leads to confusion. Always avoid confusion if possible.
- Trigger fires on update of delay_start. An update of either delay_start or delay_end also updates delay_duration.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply and provide an answer.  As mentioned I am new to this stuff.  What would be a downside to having delay_duration be its own column and using a trigger?  For my application I need to do a lot of calculations with the delay_duration, so I figured I would need it as its own column.

Comment: **It is its own column**. The only difference between it and any other column is way the value is set. **The way you use it remains exactly the same.** With generated column the derivation  is part of the definition.With triggers you are executing a hidden function. (You know its there. Will your successor? Will you remember in 2 years?) Triggers can be disabled or updated incorrectly introducing errors which are difficult to find.  Triggers can also introduce logic errors (as yours does. What happens if delay_start is updated?)  BTW I updated answer to show correct trigger.

Comment: Wow, that is a very good point.  I suppose I'm really stretching my understanding of how postgres works, particularly in conjunction with knex, which is what I'm using to pass data to the frontend.  If I do return knex('deckdelays) will the delay_duration field be pulled in with the other fields?

In looking at your initial response it seems you instantiate the generated column when you initially create the table, which would lead me to believe it is an actual column in the table and not a temporary column.  I'll give it a test in a new table and see.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Tried it, definitely the way to go.  Thanks so much Belayer.  Marking as correct answer.